# How to close accordion on second click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having accordion component which is revealed on click. I have an issue with closing it on second click. Currently I'm clicking once and it expands but after second click nothing changes. Thank you for help

```
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = React.useState(props.tabIndex);

    const tabs = props.tabs.map((tab) => {
        return (
            <>
                <TabContainer>
                    <Tab
                        key={tab.index}
                        onClick={() => setActiveTab(tab.index)}. //here it opens
                        className={typeof tab.content === 'string' ? '' : 'unactive-tab'}
                    >
                        {tab.name}
                    </Tab>
                </TabContainer>
                {tab.index === activeTab ?
                    <div
                        id="content"
                        style={{ width: '100%', margin: '2rem 0' }}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: tab.content as string }}
                    />
                    : null}
            </>
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try changing your onClick method to this

```
  onClick= {() => {
   activTab == tab.index ? setActiveTab(-1) : setActiveTab(tab.index)
  })
```

In the case where active tab matches the current index of the tab clicked, we set it to -1, hence matching no tab ( showing no tab ); else we set the active tab to the current tab clicked.